# Closure of span in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

I've got a functional analysis problem that I am not sure where to start with at the moment. Any help would be great.

If A is an arbitrary subset of a Hilbert space $(X,\langle .,. \rangle)$, then I need to show that $(A^{\perp})^{\perp}=\overline{spanA}$.

Just a nudge in the right direction would be fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: Can you at least show that $\mathrm{span}(A) \subset (A^{\perp})^{\perp}$?

Answer (score 1):

The Littlest of Nudges:

One containment is easy without a pesky bar, which can be thrown in recalling that the closure is of a set is contained in every closed set containing the est.

The other containment is easy if you show that the distance from $(A^\perp)^\perp$ to $\text{span}(A)$ is zero, which implies that (BLANK).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am able to show that the span of A is contained in $(A^{\perp})^{\perp}$ but the second containment I am finding more difficult. I am afraid I dont really understand what you mean with the second hint Alex. Could you explain what you mean by distinct?

Comment: @RobN I made a typo :) See if it makes more sense now?